# bluetooth Chat application

Tags: bluetooth, java-me

How can i make my bluetooth Chat application developed in J2ME find only devices that run the application?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server app use the same UUID as your client apps.  Many examples can be found [here](http://www.jsr82.com/).